# SQL query: get tag id and number of tag occurences

Tags: sql

I think, the answer to my question is rather simple, but I just can't figure it out at the moment. I experimented with DISTINCT() and COUNT(), but had no success, although I know, that I did it somehow once before. So:

I have three tables: `article`, `tag`, and `article_tag`. The last one is simply two columns with `article_id` and `tag_id` building a unique key.

Now I want a single SELECT statement that delivers me the `tag_id` and a count of how many times it appears in the `article_tag` table. Something like

```
| tag_id  | count   |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | 14      |
| 2       | 3       |
| 3       | 34      |
+---------+---------+
```

from a query like:

```
SELECT tag_id, COUNT(something) AS count 
  FROM article_tag
```

Could someone tell me, how I could get this result? I guess, I should stop coding when it's tending towards 0:00 o'clock...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  SELECT tag_id, 
         COUNT(article_id) AS article_count 
    FROM article_tags 
GROUP BY tag_id
```

Comment: Apparently you were the first. Thanks to all of you for the answers! As I said, I think I will stop coding around midnight.

Answer (score 3):

Try: select tag_id, count(article_id) from article_tag group by tag_id

Answer (score 3):

```
select tag_id, count(*) from article_tag group by tag_id order by tag_id;
```

You can fool around with the `order by` as well.  To see which tags have the most references:

```
  select tag_id, count(*) from article_tag group by tag_id order by count(*);
```